# What does the 'shape' function do in yup?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, yup

Most [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) examples use the *shape* method, but I find the documentation a little hard to understand why this is the case, and exactly what the method does.

Can someone please explain the difference between a schema defined with `Yup.object({...})` and `Yup.object().shape({...})`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> You can also pass a shape to the object constructor as a convenience.
>   [yupobject documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup#object)

Basically passing the schema to shape is just the long-form of passing it to the object constructor. Shape does however offer the benefit of chaining and overloading definitions in later chained methods. [See yup.shape documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup#objectshapefields-object-nosortedges-arraystring-string-schema)

Comment: Basically you can pass an initial shape to the constructor and then chain more shape() calls later. So object().shape({shape}) is really unnecessary. The documentation sort of explains this but in fragments;  had read most of it. :)